# Send to multiple emails using google script

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 5; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:I6
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 10);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var counter = 0;
  var qua_num = [[]];
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var days = row[8];
    if (days > -14) {
    var emailAddress = row[9]; // First column
      qua_num += [row[0]];
      counter += 1;
    }
  }
  var message = qua_num + ' equipment are approaching due date or out of cal. Please check with QA for replacement or sending the equipment out for re-calibration'; // Second column
  var subject = 'Check Equipment Calibration Alert';
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

The current code lets me send only to one email address from google spreadsheet. If there is a different email address in each row (multiple rows could have the same email address as well), how do I change the function? See example of the google spreadsheet below.

[Screenshot of Google Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3l8W.png)

Based on the information in the spreadsheet, QUA-005 and QUA-007 meet the condition of the if statement. The expected output would be:

Email 1 to emailaddress 1
QUA-005 equipment are approaching due date or out of cal. Please check with QA for replacement or sending the equipment out for re-calibration.

Email 2 to emailaddress 2
QUA-007 equipment are approaching due date or out of cal. Please check with QA for replacement or sending the equipment out for re-calibration.

If the email address is the same, then the output would be:

QUA-005, QUA-007 equipment are approaching due date or out of cal. Please check with QA for replacement or sending the equipment out for re-calibration.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `If there is a different email address in each row (multiple rows could have the same email address as well), how do I change the function?`. Can you explain about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike If you take a look at the spreadsheet, there are 2 different email addresses. I want to combine all the items in column 1 that have passed the IF statement with the respective email address and send them an email. I hope that explains your question. I also want to cc additional email addresses.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `all the items in column 1 that have passed the IF statement`. So can you provide the sample output values you expect? By this, I would like to think of the issue and solution.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your goal. This is due to my poor understanding. I deeply apologize for this. When I could correctly understand about it, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: @Tanaike I added to the question. Please have a look

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. From the additional information, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to send emails to the email address of the column "J", when the value of column "I" is more than `-14`.
- When there are the same email addresses of the column "J", you want to aggregate the values of column "A" and want to send them to one email address.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Modification points:

- In this modification, at first, an object is created from the values retrieved from Spreadsheet. Then, using the object, the content of email is created and send it.

### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var counter = 0;
var qua_num = [[]];
for (var i in data) {
  var row = data[i];
  var days = row[8];
  if (days > -14) {
  var emailAddress = row[9]; // First column
    qua_num += [row[0]];
    counter += 1;
  }
}
var message = qua_num + ' equipment are approaching due date or out of cal. Please check with QA for replacement or sending the equipment out for re-calibration'; // Second column
var subject = 'Check Equipment Calibration Alert';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

#### To:

```
data.reduce((m, [qua_num,,,,,,,,daysPastCal,emailAddress]) => {
  if (daysPastCal > -14) m.set(emailAddress, m.has(emailAddress) ? [...m.get(emailAddress), qua_num] : [qua_num]);
  return m;
}, new Map())
.forEach((qua_num, emailAddress) => {
  var message = qua_num.join(",") + ' equipment are approaching due date or out of cal. Please check with QA for replacement or sending the equipment out for re-calibration';
  var subject = 'Check Equipment Calibration Alert';
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
});
```

### Note:

- In this case, please enable V8 at the script editor.

### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Thanks for the help here @tanaike. I am now trying to aggregate the values of multiple columns (not just column A). How can I map in that case? Your help is very much appreciated.